# Adding CSS Class According to Image Ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, class

I'm creating an image gallery with dozens of landscape and portrait images on a single page. I want to style each image with a dynamically added CSS class (i.e. ".landscape" for landscape images) according to its orientation.

I came across the code below (from 2003!) For determining the ratio and adding a class for a single image, but I need the classes to be added automatically for all images within a certain div id. Honestly, I just don't know enough about JavaScript or jQuery to solve this on my own.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function getDim() {
myImage = new Image;
myImage.src="myimage.gif";//path to image
document.divImage.src=myImage.src;
var imgProp;
var width = myImage.width;
var height = myImage.height;
var ratio = width/height;
if ( ratio > 1 ) {
document.getElementById('image').className="portrait";
}
else {
document.getElementById('image').className="landscape";
}
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

with jQuery:

```
$('#divID img').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
});
```

Comment: Um, wow. 3 Answers in less than 14 hours. You guys are awesome! I'll start with @cwolves's solution this morning and let you know how it goes! WOOT!

Comment: . . . And it works flawlessly! Unfortunately, the CMS I'm using doesn't return the image height and width info. Luckily, my CMS developer is pretty good about change requests, so hopefully he'll add that info to the XML output today! THANKS CWOLVES and all the others who joined in!

Comment: Nice and sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward jQuery:

```
$('#yourId').find('img').each(function(i,elem){
    var $this = $(this),
        ratio = $this.width() / $this.height();

    $this.addClass((ratio < 1) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
});
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/dYah8/1/)

Comment: Um, wow. 3 Answers in less than 14 hours. You guys are awesome! I'll start with @cwolves solution this morning and let you know how it goes! WOOT!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, that your containing div is of class `gallery` and you are using jQuery :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery img').each(function(){
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var className;
        if (width/height > 1) className = "portrait";
        else className = "landscape";
        $(this).addClass(className);
    });
});
```

This way is longer, but allows you to add more rules (if there is any reason to do so :).. ie.:

```
if (width/height == 1) className = "square";
```

Comment: `$(this).width()` is wasteful.  You unnecessarily create the same jQuery object _3_ times and you're using jQuery to do something it doesn't need to do which is just check `this.width`

Comment: Ah, I thought $(this) will use reference.

Comment: It references the image, yes, but you're unnecessarily creating 3 different jQuery objects.  It doesn't take up that much memory/space in this example, but getting into the habit of doing `var $this = $(this)`, or something similar is good.  Also, getting out of the habit of using jQuery for _everything_, e.g. `.width()` when `.width` on the DOM node gives you the same thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking about var image = $(this), but I didn't use it in the end.. the result would be same anyway, if it does use reference. And I am not that skilled with pure javascript, so I didn't know about simple .width so thanks for poinint that out. Glad to learn something :)

Answer (score 0):

If setting img width/height interferes with your css, you can set it as data-width/data-height:

```
  $('#your-div-Id').find('img').each(function(i,elem){
      var $this = $(this),
          ratio = $this.attr('data-width') / $this.attr('data-height');
      $this.addClass((ratio < 1) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="your-div-Id">
    <img src="#" data-width="60" data-height="30" />
</div>
```

[Edited mVChr's example](http://jsfiddle.net/dYah8/49/)